# Template Path Hints not showing on front-end in magento2

Tags: magento2, debug, template-hints

- In my case, after enable the path Hints, from magento2 back-end section, its not showing. I enabled the settings in.

  > Store > Configuration > Advanced > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

  Can anyone tell me how fix this ?

  [image]

Comment: Yes, I already select to scope .but it seems not fixed.

Comment: Are you in production mode ?

Comment: No,working on local server.

Comment: You need to set Default Store view instead of Main website in your current scope.

Comment: m2.3 use storurl/?templatehints=magento

Comment: http://localhost?templatehints=magento This worked for me
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 22):

As @matinict mentioned in his comment, in **Magento 2.3** you need to append `?templatehints=<Parameter Value>` in your URL and your magento should be on **Developer mode**.

So your url will be look like as following:

> http://localhost?templatehints=magento

and for any particular page URL will be like that

> http://localhost/checkout/cart/?templatehints=magento

[image]

Comment: it works for me

Answer (score 20):

For future googlers - I had this same problem on a site that had the core Magento data migrated over from an M1 store I had no control over. The problem turned out to be an IP address in the developer client restrictions input. This overrides template hints.

[image: developer ip restrictions input in Magento 2 admin area]

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: Does not work, it still not shows.
Edit: I had to set the store view to my store view in the upper left. There were also IP's entered in it.

Comment: @Black cool, this was also my case.

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: Appreciate you!

Answer (score 9):

You need to set scope `Default store view` or your current store view.
You have set Main Website in Current configuration scope.

[image]

**After set Current configuration as YOur Default store view and check Yes for storepath hints for front and Blockpath hints as Yes.**

Comment: thnks to all, its worked.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was also wrong scope

Answer (score 3):

If  you are using **Magento 2.2** then on ***production mode***, the template hint will not work.

Also, you need to check  the setting at  ***last level of scope*** mean ***store view scope***.

Comment: How to view Template Path Hints for Storefront in Production Mode?

Comment: You cannot do at Production. Need to some customization

Comment: Can i get any idea how to do the customization regard path hints?

Answer (score 3):

**I strongly discourage this method. Use it at your own risk. Only to be used on local system.**

Open `vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Plugin/DebugHints.php` (tested in 2.3.2)

write this code inside `afterCreate` function : (at the start, above the storecode line)

```
if(isset($_GET['shreyasPathHints']) && $_GET['shreyasPathHints'] == 'on'){
    return $this->debugHintsFactory->create([
        'subject' => $invocationResult,
        'showBlockHints' => 1,
    ]);
}
```

Now, you can open any Magento page and append `?shreyasPathHints=on` to the URL. No need to run any commands.

Answer (score 2):

Curiously. Now it works. Added a new block on the site and once again cleared the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to put in my two cents as well. After scratching my head about why template hints weren't being displayed even though the setting is enabled, I eventually discovered that the ?templatehints={key} bit does not work with urls that include pagination, eg:

https://devserver1234.nxcli.net/mycategory.html?p=1?templatehints=magento

In this case, you would need to remove the **?p=1** portion of the url.

Comment: If you have multiple parameters in an URL, separate them with an ampersand (&):
https://devserver1234.nxcli.net/mycategory.html?p=1&templatehints=magento